# Google Sheets query, transpose, split, flatten?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am not a programmer but am trying to do the following for my school: we have a Google Sheet file (auto-generated and updated real-time from a Google Form) that outputs something like this:

[Output from Google Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyIA8.png)

[image]

I want to reference that data in a separate sheet and make it look like this:

[What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d209.png)

[image]

I've spent a few hours digging our this site and others trying to find a solution, but I'm lost in a language I don't know... Any help provided would be much appreciated!

Comment: So you want to do a reverse pivot table

Comment: From what I've read––yes. I just don't know how to code that. Is there an example you can point me to?

Comment: As a hint I would use  Class (which is e.values[1] from the onFormSubmit object as the property names and if the property doesn't exist then I'd create one and make it an array and split the contents on comma and push them into the array for that property.  I'd also use an object array that holds a litst of all of the propeties so that I can list them out later.  If the property already exists them I would just split the contents and push them into the array for that property.  If you comfortable using objects you should have no trouble.  I would put all of the names in the same column.

Comment: If you'll post your data as a table so that we can copy it I think someone will end up giving you an example code.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, Cooper. Here is a link to my table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ven0b6pwcESWsA4rckoMCt7TAEeFfficbcOi_4HOUOw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't follow links to offsite resources.  But others do.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
={"Class","Name";ARRAYFORMULA(split(flatten(Data!B2:B4&"|"&arrayformula(trim((split(transpose(query(transpose(Data!C2:E4),,columns(Data!C2:E4))),","))))),"|"))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same thing for my Google form response sheets. Here is a piece of the code.

```
function findTransLoc(inId) {
  console.log('Begin findTransLoc');
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  console.log('                    inId: ', inId );  
  const destSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(inId)
  let srcShtNm = getTabNm(destSs)
  
  let srcSht = destSs.getSheetByName(srcShtNm);
  const destShtNm = srcShtNm + 'xd';
  let destSht = destSs.getSheetByName(destShtNm);
  if ( destSht ) {
    console.log('clearing existing destination sheet: ', destShtNm  );
    destSht.clear();
  }    else    {
    destSht = destSs.insertSheet(destShtNm);
  }
   
  var srcRng = srcSht.getDataRange();
  var srcRows = srcRng.getLastRow();
  console.log('srcRows: ', srcRows );
  var srcCols = srcRng.getLastColumn();;
  console.log('srcCols: ', srcCols );
  var srcDataArr = srcRng.getValues();
  var resultArr = [],promptList;
  for (var col = 0; col < srcCols; col++) { // Loop over array cols
    resultArr[col] = [];
    for (var row = 0; row < srcRows; row++) { // Loop over array rows
      console.log('row: ', row, ' col: ', col, ' ', srcDataArr[row][col] );
      resultArr[col][row] = srcDataArr[row][col].toString(); // Rotate
    }
  }
  console.log('resultArr: ' , JSON.stringify(resultArr) );
  destSht.getRange(1, 1, srcCols, srcRows ).setValues(resultArr);
}
```

I generalized it to let me choose any tab in the spreadsheet so have this code

```
function getTabNm(destSs)  {
  console.log('Begin getTabNm');
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var sheetList = [], tabNm, promptList = '', i = 1, srcSht;
  destSs.getSheets().forEach(function(val){
    tabNm = val.getName();
    promptList = promptList + i + ': ' + tabNm + '\n';
    sheetList.push([i,tabNm]);
    i++
  });
  
  console.log('promptList: ', promptList );
  console.log( JSON.stringify(sheetList) );  
  
    let result = ui.prompt(
    'Which tab do you want to work with? Enter the number?\n' +
    promptList +
    '\n_____Click close button or cancel with the X to quit.',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  let button = result.getSelectedButton();  
  let inTxt = result.getResponseText();
  let parsed = parseInt(inTxt, 10);
  if (isNaN(parsed)) { parsed = 0; }
  console.log('inTxt: ', inTxt, ' parsed: ', parsed );
  srcShtNm = sheetList[parsed-1][1];  // zero based array
  console.log('returning  srcShtNm: ', srcShtNm ); 
  return srcShtNm;
}
```

If you don't want this, take out the call to getTabNm:

```
  let srcShtNm = getTabNm(destSs)
  let srcSht = destSs.getSheetByName(srcShtNm);
```

and add this single line to get the current sheet.

```
let srcSht = destSs.getActiveSheet();
```

I have a lot of other 'bells and whistles' you may be interested in in my code. Feel free to make a copy and communicate with me for questions or suggestions.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Amy8LgeCdl8RsDr98pEVXVSqrMzGqMc_VuLYQy94mC8/edit?usp=sharing